# Rails 4 how to validate email against rfc822

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, email, rfc822

I'm using default rails EmailValidator to check my emails like this

EmailValidator:

```
class EmailValidator < ActiveModel::EachValidator
  def validate_each(record, attribute, value)
    unless value =~ /\A([^@\s]+)@((?:[-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,})\z/i
      record.errors.add attribute, :invalid
    end
  end
end
```

and USer model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :email, presence: true, uniqueness: true, email: true
```

But this did not catch cyrillic emails as invalid. I know that i can change regular expression with this one http://www.ex-parrot.com/pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html but I'm wondering if there is easiest way, with gem or something. I've installed rfc-822 but now i don't know how  to use it. Description here https://github.com/dim/rfc-822/blob/master/lib/rfc822.rb#L27 says to add `validates_format_of :email, :with => RFC822::EMAIL` to model but when I do, this is what I receive

`NameError: uninitialized constant User::RFC822`

what I'm missing ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you add the gem to the `Gemfile` of your Ruby on Rails project?

```
# Gemfile
gem 'rfc-822'
```

Run bundle afterwards and restart your server. Next time, the constant `RFC822` should be available. You can test this easily by opening the Ruby on Rails console with `rails c` and then run `RFC822::EMAIL` for example, which should print some regular expression.

Comment: I did not alter the Gemfile... tnx